# Variance of a r.v. on a non-centered circle

Tags: probability, expectation, polar-coordinates, variance

I'm working on a question where I have to evaluate, amongst others, the variance of X and Y, where (X,Y) are uniformly distributed in the unit circle centered in (1,2).

Since this is a unit circle, $f_{xy}=\frac{1}{\pi}$.

I started by converting X and Y to polar coordinates: $x=rcos(\theta)+1$. I then calculated $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$

$$E(X)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}rcos(\theta)+1  drd\theta =2$$
$$E(X^2)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}(rcos(\theta)+1)^2 drd\theta =\frac{7}{3}$$

I checked my integrals, and they give the correct result.

As you might have noticed, $E(X^2)-E(X)^2=-\frac{5}{3}$. Thus, the variance is negative. Where is my mistake? I have a feeling it might be related to my polar coordinates...

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[\cdots] = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (\cdots) \color{red}{r} drd\theta$

Comment: @achillehui I can't believe I made such an amateurish mistake... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are concerned with variance you might as well have the circle centered at the origin. Then,
\begin{align}
Var(X)=E(X^2)
&= {1\over2\pi}\int_{x=-1}^1\int_{y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}x^2\,dx\,dy\\
&= {1\over2\pi}\int_{x=-1}^1 x^2\,2\sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx\\
&= {1\over8}.
\end{align}